# How do I fix this strange UIDatePicker behavior?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

UIDatePicker looks okay on the XCode iPhone 5S Simulator but not on my iPhone 5S - it renders off center and too big. How do I fix it?

Thanks

[iPhone 5S running UIDatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axJWV.png)

[XCode iPhone 5S Simulator running UIDatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJPGC.png)

UPDATE: the "Autoresize Subviews" setting in IB seems to have been the culprit... I unchecked it and the picker now works

Comment: It would help to see `how do you manage your layout` (*pure storybook constraints: which ones or from code: show a bit*).

Comment: constraints used: http://imgur.com/a/iTf3L

Comment: seems like you don't have a trailing constraint

Comment: @washloops added one for the datepicker and it didn't change anything